# Resolve "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question regarding how I can fix 'Can't perform a React state update' error message. I did read a little further into the issue and states it is only a warning. Please note, I'm a beginner at React. Here is the problem as follows.
I have a header component that is comprised of a navbar that has two states for toggling the mobile navigation menu button and another for changing background-color on scroll.  I implemented navbar toggle functionality and I started receiving the so-called error in JS console. Upon further inspection, I have determined that it is something to do with my toggle state.  Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'react-icons-kit';
import {bars} from 'react-icons-kit/fa/bars';
import {times} from 'react-icons-kit/fa/times';
import {chevronCircleDown} from 'react-icons-kit/fa/chevronCircleDown';

const Header = (props) => {
    
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);    
const [navbar, setNavbar] = useState(false); 
                                                 
   const handleToggle = () => {
       setToggle(!toggle);
      }                                           
       
   const changeBackground = () => {
          if(window.scrollY >= 60) {
               setNavbar(true);
          } 
          else {
              setNavbar(false);
          }
      }     
   
   window.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);

     

            if(props.data){
      var description = props.data.description;   
      var navigation = props.data.navigation.map(item => {
    return <li key={item.linkname} className="nav-item"><a href={item.href} className={item.className}>{item.linkname}</a></li> 
      });    
    }
                                                      
                                            
    return (
      <header id="home" className="main-header">                                         
           <div className="container">
              <nav className={navbar ? 'navbar nav-bg' : 'navbar'} aria-label="Main Navigation" id="navbar">
           <ul className={toggle ? 'navbar-nav active' : 'navbar-nav'} id="nav">
             {navigation}
           </ul>
           <button className="btn-mobile-nav" type="button" aria-controls="nav" aria-expanded={toggle ? 'true' : 'false'} aria-label="Mobile Navigation button" title="Mobile menu button" onClick={handleToggle}>{toggle ? <Icon icon={times} size={24} title="Close Menu"/> : <Icon icon={bars} size={24} title="Open Menu"/> }</button>
      </nav>
        </div>
               <div className="header-content d-flex flex-column">
           <div>
               <h1 className="header-title"><span className="typed"></span></h1>
               <p className="header-summary">{description}</p>
           </div>
       </div>
       <a href="#about" id="to-about" className="btn-up-down" title="Go to About" aria-label="Go to About section"> <Icon icon={chevronCircleDown} size={54}/></a>
   </header>
    );
    
}

export default Header;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import SkipNav from './Components/SkipNav';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import About from './Components/About';
import Resume from './Components/Resume';
import Portfolio from './Components/Portfolio';
import Contact from './Components/Contact';



class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {   
      resumeData: [],
      recipName: '',
      recipEmail: '',
      recipSubject: '',
      recipMessage: ''    
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCaptchaChange = this.handleCaptchaChange.bind(this);
    this.handleEmailSent = this.handleEmailSent.bind(this);  
  }

  getResumeData = () => {
   fetch('/data.json')
   .then(response => {
    return response.json()
   })
   .then(data => {
     this.setState({
       resumeData: data
     });
   })
   .catch(error => {
     console.log(error)  
     alert(`Unable to retrieve data! See JS console for details. Error:${error}`)
   })
   }
  
  handleChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }
  
  handleCaptchaChange = (value) => {
  console.log("Captcha value:", value);
}
  
  handleEmailSent = (event) => {
    
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.recipName === '' || this.state.recipEmail === '' || this.state.recipSubject === '' || this.state.recipMessage === '') {
          console.log('All fields required!')
          alert('All fields are required!');
          return;
      }
    
     let data = {
      recipName: this.state.recipName,
      recipEmail: this.state.recipEmail,
      recipSubject: this.state.recipSubject,     
      recipMessage: this.state.recipMessage
    };
    console.log(data);
    
    
        fetch (`https://api.eahassan.me/sendEmail`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        alert("E-Mail sent successfully!");
        window.location.reload();    
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("E-Mail Failure - Error:", error));  
  }


  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getResumeData(); 
  }

  render() {
      
      
      
    return (
        
       <div className="App">
          <SkipNav title="Skip to main content"/>
          <Header data={this.state.resumeData.main}/>
            <main id="mainContent">
              <About data={this.state.resumeData.main} title="About Me"/>
              <Resume data={this.state.resumeData.resume} eduTitle="Education" workTitle="Work" skillTitle="Skills"/>
              <Portfolio data={this.state.resumeData.portfolio}/>
              <Contact data={this.state.resumeData.main} recommendData={this.state.resumeData.recommendations} captchaChange={this.handleCaptchaChange} recipName={this.state.recipName} recipEmail={this.state.recipEmail} recipSubject={this.state.recipSubject} recipMessage={this.state.recipMessage} EmailSend={this.handleEmailSent} change={this.handleChange}/>
         </main>
         <Footer data={this.state.resumeData.main}/>
      </div> 
        
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Are you using the useEffect hook in any of your components? If yes, could I see where?

Comment: Actually, I'm not using the useEffect hook.

Comment: Could you please try adding this?


`useEffect(() => {
 window.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);
 
 return () => {
   window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);
 }
});`

Comment: Is there anything else I can provide with my code? I'm not familiar with useEffect.

Comment: Ok, I will try and let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: In short, you place this line `window.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground)` inside of your useEffect hook. It adds the event listener when the component first mounts and removes the event when it unmounts.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It works.  I'm still receiving the error though.  The first error on the App component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242611/discussion-between-vinicius-cerqueira-bonifacio-and-evan-h).

Comment: Can you try commenting out chunks of code in `App` to see what area the issue is originating from? Comment out `componentDidMount` and everything in the `<div className="App">` div, then one-by-one uncomment an element/component until it throws the warning, then drill into *that* component/element and repeat until you find exactly where the issue is.

Comment: Ok, I will try that and let you know what happens.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe componentDidMount is triggering the error.

Comment: Does commenting out `componentDidMount` so `getResumeData` isn't called make the warning go away?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: All that's doing is fetching a JSON file and enqueueing a state update. Is the `App` component being remounted for some reason? What debugging have you done here? Drop a `console.log("App mounted");` in `componentDidMount` and check if more than one log occurs when starting the app.

Comment: I figured out that the JS console output logs App mounted twice.  Something going on with the App component.  Not sure, why it is being called twice or the cause???

Answer (score 2):

You are unconditionally adding a scroll event listener in the body of the component. This should be added in an `useEffect` hook and cleaned up when the component unmounts. For scroll events that are generally very noisy, you'll want to make these [passive listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters).

```
useEffect(() => {
  const changeBackground = () => {
    setNavbar(window.scrollY >= 60);
  }
  window.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground, { passive: true });

  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeBackground, { passive: true });
}, []);
```

Comment: I'm still receiving the error, which refers to App component. I mean the first error.  Navbar scroll effect issue is resolved. It works.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The App component's constructor function was being rendered twice.
I removed <React.StrictMode> from index.js and the error went away.
Problem solved!

https://arange.github.io/2020-06-15-react-component-s-constructor-rendered-twice-leading-to-bugs-using-axios-interceptor/